# Having problems saving and or returning\displaying a valid image file using FileContentResult and HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

If I call the GetImage action method directly ie: `localserver/admin/GetImage?ProductID=36` it prompts me to download the file. Upon download, even when the file has the correct extension it does not open, testing with regular *.jpeg images from my pictures folder.
Also how do I set the filename when saving the file to database, do I need to create additional varchar type etc. field in database just for the filename ?

Once assigned to productMedia.ImageData the data is also all zeroes, hence null. Unlike the "image", which has varying digits in there. Maybe it should be image.InputStream.Write and not image.InputStream.Read ? Tried it but still no go.

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveProduct", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Here's the saving procedure:

```
   if (image != null)
            {
                var ProductMedia = new ProductMedia();
                ProductMedia.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                ProductMedia.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(ProductMedia.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);
                ProductMedia.ProductID = product.ProductID;
                context.ProductMedias.AddObject(ProductMedia);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

and the GetImage method:

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int productID)
        {

            var ProductImages = context.ProductMedias.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == productID);

            if (ProductImages != null)
            {

                return File(ProductImages.ImageData, ProductImages.ImageMimeType);

            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your `GetImage` method check your saving procedure for correct content type correct data. And in database check whether you have enough size for the image in `ImageData` column.
For the second question , Yes you need a separate column for file name.

Comment: using varbinary(MAX) for ImageData

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax that should be used and it works.

```
        if (image != null)
        {

            var product = new Product();

            product.FileName = image.FileName; //<- optional filename
            product.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
            int length = image.ContentLength;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            image.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
            product.ImageData = buffer;

          //Save product to database 

        }
```